# How to display content with checkbox More Field plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Plugin More Fields to display some content in page. But field "Checkbox" don't work.

```
<!-- Widget Productos destacados / Featured products -->
    <div id="cdm_carrusel">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $featuredprod = new WP_Query();
            $featuredprod->query('posts_per_page=3&post_type=products');
            while($featuredprod->have_posts()) {
                $featuredprod->the_post();
            ?>
                <!--if checkbox is checked, display list-->
                <?php if (meta('producto-destacado')) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <!--else, if not checked, don't display content-->
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <!--Nothing -->
                <?php } ?>
            <?php
            }           
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // Widget Productos destacados / Featured products -->
```

Any suggest?

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```php
<!--if checkbox is checked, display list-->
     <?php if (meta('producto-destacado')) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <!--else, if not checked, don't display content-->
      <?php } else { ?>
          <!--Nothing -->
      <?php } ?>
```

With this:

```php
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'producto-destacado', true) ) : ?>
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That should get the job done for you as long as you don't need an `else` statement in there.  Little different if you do.